# Please explain: Line skipped after for loop?

Tags: c++, control-flow

I'm trying to do my first baby steps with C++.

Can somebody explain why this does not work the way I'd expect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    printf("[D] sizeof argv is: %d\n", sizeof(argv) );
    printf("[D] sizeof int  is: %d\n", sizeof(int) );
    printf(
        "[D] sizeof argv / sizeof int is: %d\n",
        sizeof(argv) / sizeof(int)
    );

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(argv) / sizeof(int)); i++ ) {
        printf("[D] i is: %d\n", i );
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    if (cout.fail()) {
        printf("cout failed!\n");
    }

    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

Now the testing:

```
aloism@azzgoat:~/sandbox/tuts$ g++ string02-d.cpp
aloism@azzgoat:~/sandbox/tuts$ ./a.out hello world
[D] sizeof argv is: 8
[D] sizeof int  is: 4
[D] sizeof argv / sizeof int is: 2
[D] i is: 0
./a.out
[D] i is: 1
hello
Hello world
aloism@azzgoat:~/sandbox/tuts$ ./a.out
[D] sizeof argv is: 8
[D] sizeof int  is: 4
[D] sizeof argv / sizeof int is: 2
[D] i is: 0
./a.out
[D] i is: 1
cout failed!
aloism@azzgoat:~/sandbox/tuts$ echo $?
0
aloism@azzgoat:~/sandbox/tuts$
```

Why when there is only one item in argv (argv[0], being "./a.out"), the "Hello world" is skipped?  I can't find any reason at all why this would be skipped, no matter the argc or argv!

The OS is Debian Squeeze on 64-bit (so `sizeof(int) == 4`).

**Update:** Removed #include noise, added some debugging.

**Update 2:** Added some debugging based on user315052's answer.  (Now it shows that he's right.)

Comment: It should be `for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)`... What, do you think, is that `ARGument Count` parameter for?

Comment: By the way that's not **C++**, that's not even a valid function declaration in **C++**! It should be `int main...`

Comment: You don't use either `<string>` or `<stdlib.h>`. In a C++ program, you should probably use `<cstdlib>` when you need services from the C `<stdlib.h>` header.

Comment: @AloisMahdal Whatever you do, please don't explain where "azzgoat" comes from. I don't want to know.

Comment: You should try your program as `./a.out hello world this is the universe calling`; it will probably produce just `./a.out`, `hello`, and `Hello world`.

Comment: @MrLister You made me ROFL like hell so sorry, now I have to: ID of my VPS assigned by provider is "422900047"; the rest is just a L33T imagination :) I'm not native English speaker, I hoped that the punch wouldn't be so horrible :)

Comment: @AloisMahdal I'm sorry too. As I don't have suggestions or solutions, I have no business commenting in here. My apologies.

Comment: It is often not a good idea to use `printf` in C++. It is unsafe, and `std::cout` is better.

Comment: @Zyx2000 While there certainly must be a background to your comment, I think that this example clearly shows that even `cout` (if used improperly) can be dangerous, too: it failed silently.  Unless I checked `cout.fail()`, it just ate the "Hello world" with no warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** since undefined behavior is invoked, anything can happen. Adjusting answer.

The "Hello World" is probably not being skipped. Realize your `for` loop is improper. One reason that it may not be appearing is that you have printed something that is covering up the appearance of the message. To test this, redirect the output into something that will reveal binary contents of the output stream.

```
./a.out | xxd
```

Another reason may be that the output is being blocked because `std::cout` suffered a failure from an attempt to print a `NULL` pointer as a string. To test for this, check for `std::cout.fail()` after the print statement in your loop, and direct a message to `std::err` if you encounter one.

The program may also crash, as indicated by Boann. However, the operating system would have provided a diagnostic to that effect, and you reported no such behavior.

For arrays that are function parameters, the compiler treats them as a pointer. This is a behavior inherited from C, where arrays are passed by "reference" by allowing the name of an array to decay to the address of its first element (with a few exceptions, `sizeof` being one of them). So, using `sizeof` to determine the number of elements in `argv` won't work. Both C and C++ provide two ways to determine when the end of the `argv` vector is reached. One is `argc` which is the argument count. The second is that the last element of `argv` must be a `NULL` pointer.

The next time you have a true array, you can calculate the number of elements with `sizeof` using the following:

```
SomeThing array[] = { /* ... things ... */ };
size_t array_size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

This way, if `SomeThing` changes, the array size is still properly calculated.

Comment: Or, better yet, `./a.out | hd`.

Comment: `xxd` nor `hd` did not reveal "Hello world" anywhere :/

Comment: @Griwes: Thanks for the input, I don't have `hd` on my system, but I do think a pipe is better. Edit made. Regards

Comment: @AloisMahdal: I updated my answer, there is another reason it might not be printing.

Comment: You are right that `cout` is blocked and fails silently, and `cout.fail()` returns true to indicate it.  OS does not seem to care :) (Updated Q to show why I'm accepting this 
A.)

Comment: @AloisMahdal: Glad to have helped. +1 on your question from me.

Answer (score 5):

Your sizeof check is faulty and always evaluates to 2 [on 64-bit]. Consequently, when you don't give the program at least one argument, it tries to print from unmapped memory at `argv[1]`, and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your error. "Hello World" is printed in both cases for me.

```
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$ ./a.out 
./a.out
Hello world
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$ ./a.out Hello
./a.out
Hello world
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$
```

Can you check if there is any core dump maybe?

Comment: There is no core dump, and `$?` is zero.

Comment: Ok so possibly it is printing some junk that is backspacing over your Hello World. Can you do `./a.out | hd` like @Griwes says

Comment: "I am not able to reproduce your error." kjp meet undefined behaviour, undefined behaviour meet kjp.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes. 32 bit VirtualBox

Comment: Then you (almost certainly) have `sizeof argv / sizeof(int) == 1`, no opportunity for error or undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kjp Q is related to 64-bit system.  You could try my debugging version and post output here, just for illustration how another error (that "Hello" from argv is not printed) can propagate on other arch.